# How to use JSDoc type hints for NPM/internal modules without importing them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

Usually, when I want to refference a class in JSDoc but do not need to import it, I do this, here `SimpleLRU` is an actual class I wrote:

```
/** @typedef {import("../js/SimpleLRU.js").default} SimpleLRU **/
```

Then I can do this, without actually depending on it:

[image]

You can see hints on some methods the class has. What I am doing now is I want to have am express route function in a separate file, due to its length. But I still want hints on the `request`, `response` and `next` arguments that express will pass to it. SO I did this, remember, I don't need express here:

```
/** @typedef {import("express").default} express **/

/**
 * @param {express.Request} request
 * @param {express.Response} response
 */
function my_router(request, response, next) {

}

export default my_router;
```

But if I write `request.` I don't get any hints. If I replace the typedef with actual import, it works immediatelly:

```
import express from "express"
```

[image]

Same situation if I tried node internal package like `fs`. So how do I do this for internal packages, the way it works for me for local files?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in this way. On `typedef` I have removed default

```js
/** @typedef {import("express")} express **/
```

When I have setted the params on javadocs I have used brackets

```js
/**
 * @param {express["request"]} request
 * @param {express["response"]} response
 */
function my_router(request, response, next) {

}
```

If it doesn't work try installing `@types/express` too

Let me know :)